# SpatiaLite : update table with a spatial relationships

Tags: sql, spatialite, spatial-relationship

In a SpatiaLite DB, I am trying to update the value of a set of entities of a layer (*table1*) selected by a spatial relationship (*equals*) with entities from another layer (*table2*)

I can perform a simple selection that take about **1 minute** with this request :

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1, table2
WHERE EQUALS(table1.geom, table2.geom);
```

I can perform the update but it takes about **1 hour** with this request :

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = 1
WHERE table.id IN (
SELECT table.id FROM table1, table2
WHERE EQUALS(table1.geom, table2.geom));
```

When I try this request which I hope could take the same time as the first request :

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = 1
WHERE EQUALS(table1.geom, table2.geom);
```

I get this error :

```
SQL error: no such column: table2.geom
```

I wonder if I can do the update faster than the second request. If I do it with QGIS, first the selection, then the update it very fast but I need to do it with SpatiaLite.

Comment: For information, I use spatialite-gui

Comment: Taking a minute is a string indicator you are not using a spatial index. Indexing is __not__ automatic in spatialite - you need to include it in your query. Check the spatialite cookbook documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your update query is taking so long is that you are running the first query (the SELECT table1.*...) again and again for each  row of table1.

Why not just create a new table with your first query?

```
CREATE TABLE table3 as SELECT table1.* FROM table1, table2
WHERE EQUALS(table1.geom, table2.geom);
SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn(table3, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution a few time after asking my question but it also took 1 hour